# Alternative to Piazza for online Q&A

Tags: lecture-tools, distance-learning, online

Piazza recently started serving ads.  Are there any reasonable alternatives to Piazza that are effective for CS courses, for handling questions from students online?  I would find it useful to be able to follow the Stack Exchange model as much as possible.